# jquery- how to get different page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is one hyperlink in One.html and when I click on that link then window Two.html page having some images open[window.open('Two.html','mywindow','width=400,height=200')]

I want, when I click on image on window then that same image will also appear in One.html

Below is my attempt:

One.html

```
<a id="id1" href="" onclick="window.open('OnclickPage.html','mywindow','width=400,height=200')">Click here</a>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Two.html

```
<img id="id1" class="img" src="image.gif"/><p/>
<img id="id2" class="img" src="cart.jpg"/><p/>    

$.get("One.html").find($'area').append(clicked image from current window);//exactly not getting. please help me to correct
```

Please help me to correct page Two.html code.

All selected images from Two.html(reside in window) should instantly appear in One.html, like if we select one image then previous page should instantly updated with that image and if we select two images then previous page One.html should get updated instantly

Any kind of startup help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: $.get("One.html").find('#area').append(clicked image from current window);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `opener` object in two.html.
The `opener` object is a reference to the window that opened the new window.
Then, `$(opener.document).find('#area')...` should work..

Answer (score 0):

its have very limited option to able do that for the security levels of the different browsers 
what u can do inside iframe while its same domain origin access the Dom of the page within iframe and without.
run thu Ajax into different page not possible for the reason i told u herE:)
hope i help